# WPF DataGrid: Making the column type dynamic for every row

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid`. In one column I currently show a `ComboBox` with values of an `enum`. The code looks like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Solution">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <ComboBox ItemsSource="{utils:Enumerate {x:Type EnumSolution}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Solution, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <ComboBox ItemsSource="{utils:Enumerate {x:Type EnumSolution}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Solution, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But I do not want to display the ComboBox for all rows. I only want to display it for specific rows and just a text for the other rows. Is that possible like this:

[image: screenshot datagrid]

Comment: Use `CellTemplateSelector`

Comment: Looks promising. I'll test it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CellTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8).

First create a class that represents your selector - the logic what template to choose when:

```
public class MyCellTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate SolutionTextBlockTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SolutionComboboxTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var diff = item as YourDatGridRowObjectType;
        if(diff != null)
        {
            if (<your condition on when to choose this template>))
                return SolutionTextBlockTemplate;
            return SolutionComboboxTemplate;
        }
        return null;
    }        
}
```

In the control that contains the `DataGrid` you define the resources for that - how the templates actually look like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SolutionTextBlockTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Solution}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SolutionComboBoxTemplate">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{utils:Enumerate {x:Type connectToEcomp:EnumSolution}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Solution, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataTemplate> 
</Window.Resources>
```

In the `DataGrid` itself you use those templates like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Solution" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
        <local:MyCellTemplateSelector 
             SolutionTextBlockTemplate="{StaticResource SolutionTextBlockTemplate}" 
             SolutionComboboxTemplate="{StaticResource SolutionComboBoxTemplate}" />
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>  
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way:

Put content control to DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="Test" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyControl}"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Then create content property in your class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }

    public Control MyControl
    {
        get
        {
            return GetControlForName();
        }
    }

    Control GetControlForName()
    {
        if (Name == "textbox")
        {
            var textBox = new TextBox();
            Binding binding = new Binding(nameof(Name));
            binding.Source = this;
            textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
            return textBox;
        }
        else if (Name == "combobox")
        {
            var comboBox = new ComboBox();
            comboBox.ItemsSource = MyList;
            return comboBox;
        }
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is result:

```
 public List<MyClass> MyList { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        MyList = new List<MyClass>()
        {
            new MyClass() { Name = "textbox" },
            new MyClass() { Name = "combobox", MyList = new List<string> { "1", "2" } },
            new MyClass() { Name = "textbox" },
            new MyClass() { Name = "combobox", MyList = new List<string> { "1", "2" } }
        };
    }
```

[image: Result]